# C# DataGridView バインドされたクラスではなく、バインドされたクラスのプロパティを表示する方法

Tags: c#, datagridview

お世話になります。

C#のDataGridViewにて、Listを利用してデータをバインドして表示させる方法までは辿り着きました。しかし、ListにはNumと名付けたクラスを渡しており、そのNumクラスにはValueという名のプロパティがあります。DataGridViewには、Numクラスそのものではなく、Valueのプロパティを表示させたいのですが、DataGridViewにはクラスの名前が表示されてしまいます。

確か、この手の処理には表示させたい内容をToStringメソッドで上書きすればよかったと認識していたのですが、上書きしても結果は同じでした。

DataRowなら、DisplayMemberに値をセットすればいいのですが、Listにバインドしている場合なら、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

下記がNumのコードです。

```
public class Num
{

    private BigInteger bint = 0;

    public Num()
    {
        this.bint = 0;
    }

    public Num(BigInteger value)
    {
        this.bint = value;
    }


    public new string ToString()
    {

        string s = String.Format("{0:D3}", this.bint);
        erturn s;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new string ToString()`ではなく、`override string ToString()`を試してみてください。

DataGridViewからは、おそらく、object型としてToStringが呼ばれるので、そこから見えるようにする必要があります。

overrideとnewについて
http://gacken.com/wp/program/c-sharp/2692/

Comment: ありがとうございました。その通りでした。overrideにしたらひょうじされました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。